# onclick button alerts button ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I build a code of a button with ID and I want on clicking it to alert its ID, here's my button code: `<button ID="4">Click me</button>`
I think the code should be with jquery or javascript, how could I do it?

Comment: This one's so simple, it does not deserve any help. I suggest you read and experiment on your own. good luck. :)

Comment: Javascript:-

    <button ID="4" onclick="alert(this.id);">Click me</button>

Jquery:-

    $('button').click(function(){alert(this.id)});

Comment: While it's valid in HTML5, you probably shouldn't use just numbers for an `id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy:

`<button ID="4" onclick="alert(this.id);">Click me</button>`

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple

```
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B1</button>
<button id="2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B2</button>
<button id="3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B3</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest that the user READs and TRIes him/her self before asking such a basic question

Answer (score 0):

Just add `onclick="alert(this.id)"` to it, that's all what you have to do